# UITableViewScroll in ViewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to scrolling the table in viewWillAppear to show the specific cell , but its not working , when I write the same code in ViewDidAppear with delay of 2 sec it is working but user see that scrolling. I dont want user to see that. How to scroll the table in ViewWillAppear.Using below code.

```
var rect = self.messageTableView.rectForRow(at: indPath)
self.messageTableView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
```

Comment: Tried calling on main thread? Also call `reloadData` before scrolling to rect.

Comment: Code is executing on main thread.

Comment: Have you tried `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` with `animated` set to false instead of `scrollRectToVisible`?

Comment: yes, unfortunately that also  does not work.

Comment: Call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: show some code.. where are you making data source array?

Comment: Try calling layoutIfNeeded() before calling scrollRectToVisible(). Also, try wrapping the scrollRectToVisible() with DispatchQueue.main.async() block.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Indexpath is nil or not.
Try to write your code on main thread.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into demo project.

Your mistake probably related with UITableView dataSource changes.

> Be attentive with .reloadData(). Call reloading before scroll.

[Demo project](https://github.com/MaksimVialykh/UITableViewScroll)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code in viewDidAppear method which is the last method of the view lifecycle. It will work of there. Try it.

Comment: in that case user will see the scrolling. I dont want that.

Comment: you should try scrollToRowAtIndexpath without animation. It should work fine.

Comment: also when I check the table frame I get incorrect value, but in viewDidAppear i get the correct value. Do you think this might be the issue ??

Comment: Try it in viewDidLayoutSubviews. It should work there.

Comment: You will get the exact frame of tableview only in viewDidAppear. Before that view isn't created and you wont get the exact frame and constraints are also not set for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that calling `[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]` will do what you want.

Comment: I dont want table to scrollToBottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IndexPath then you can use following method as well -

```
open func scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```